# What is the correct way to read hardware compass?

Tags: android, android-sensors

There is a compass activity in Android API Demos but it shows correct direction to north only in portrait mode on my Google Nexus One.

I've found the following code somewhere here:

```
private float[] magneticValues;
private float[] accelerometerValues;

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    switch (event.sensor.getType())
    {
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            magneticValues = event.values.clone();
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            accelerometerValues = event.values.clone();
            break;
    }

    if (magneticValues != null && accelerometerValues != null)
    {
        float[] R = new float[16];
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, null, accelerometerValues, magneticValues);
        float[] orientation = new float[3];
        SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);

        orientation[0] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[0]);
        orientation[1] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[1]);
        orientation[2] = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[2]);

        if (orientation[0] >= 360) orientation[0] -= 360;
        if (orientation[0] < 0) orientation[0] = 360 - orientation[0];
        if (orientation[1] >= 360) orientation[1] -= 360;
        if (orientation[1] < 0) orientation[1] = 360 - orientation[1];
        if (orientation[2] >= 360) orientation[2] -= 360;
        if (orientation[2] < 0) orientation[2] = 360 - orientation[2];

        azimuth = orientation[0];
        pitch = orientation[1];
        roll = orientation[2];

        updateView();
    }
}
```

but it shows nothing sensible. I can not understand how to make API demo correctly work in landscape mode or what's wrong with the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-beginners/V4pOfLn8klQ/mdL-Wh5A7tIJ

You need to remap the Geomagnetic vector according to the Gravity vector, ie you need both the Accelerometer and Magnetic Field sensors to be on and sending events